# How to get the formula of $n$th term when it has a negative sign

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I already have the answer but I don't know the formula of getting the $n$th term. 
 The sequence is like this: __, $4, 10, 16, 22$
I know the answer is $-2$ because the interval is $6$ but how do I get the formula?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence formula is $a_n=a_{n-1}+6$.

Then it's easy to derive the general formula $a_n=-2+6(n-1)=6n-8$.